# Updating a DB file in Android using Room

Tags: android, database, android-room

I have an android app and I use Room to manage the DB actions.
I want to update my db and add a new column with new data, so I first created my db outside of the app using python and I filled the db with data.

After, I just copy and pasted the new db to my app, and I overwrite the old db file.
When I ran the app, I got an error:

```
A migration from 3 to 4 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...)
```

So I created a migration like this:

```
public class Migration_3_4 extends Migration {
    public Migration_3_4() {
        super(3, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN lang TEXT");
    }
}
```

and updated the DB creation:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "movies.db")
        .addMigrations(new Migration_3_4())
        .build();
```

After that, I did not get any errors, but I got `'null'` values in the new column.
I then copy pasted again the new db, but I still see `null` values in the new column.

How can I then transfer an updated DB to my app?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values to ALL be the same value then after the ALTER you could use:-

```
database.execSQL("UPDATE movies SET lang = 'whatever value you want';");
```

The above could be altered to SET the lang based other columns.

Alternately you can tell Room to use a default value via the `@ColumnInfo` annotation e.g.

```
@ColumnInfo(default="whatever value you want")
String lang;
```

. Noting that you would then need the ALTER to also have the DEFAULT otherwise Room will crash due to the mismatching schemas, so the ALTER would become:-

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN lang TEXT DEFAULT 'whatever value you want'");
```

If you want to introduce a database (the new db) created or modified using another SQLite tool, then it's a little more complex. But basically you put the externally modified database in the assets folder and then copy the data from the new db from the assets folder in the migration or can use the `createFromAsset` (if the database file does not exist).

Noting that for a published App then you need to cater for new and existing users so you could need a mix of migration and `createFromAsset`.